# Motivate that $\int_{\mathbb R }-x\sin (tx) e^{-x^2/2 }dx=\int_{\mathbb R }-t \cos (tx) e^{-x^2/2 }dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Consider the eqution
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb R }-x\sin (tx) e^{-x^2/2 }dx=\int_{\mathbb R }-t \cos (tx) e^{-x^2/2 }dx$$
>
> I would like to motivate why it is true.

I suppose we could use integration by parts but I get confused wich two functions I should group together. Is there a "smooth" way of seeing how this should be solved or do we have to try out the different combinations to see what they yield? I thought I could learn something here as I dont do integration by parts regularly!

[Please take it as a known fact that $\sin (tx) e^{-x^2/2 } $ is the product of an odd and an even function and thus integrate to zero over any interval $(-a,a) $.]

Most grateful for any help provided!

Comment: First of all, get rid of the minus signs on both sides; the formula looks nicer without them and they add nothing by being there.  Next, you *should* integrate by parts.  For one-dimensional integration there are essentially only two general methods: substitution and integration by parts.  This problem will show you the usefulness of integration by parts. Maybe you should ask *how* to pick $u$ and $dv$ for integration by parts instead of trying to avoid it. Let $dv$ be the hardest piece of the integral you currently know how to integrate, which in this case (on the left) is $xe^{-x^2/2}$.